# Conditional module importing in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyside, maya

I'm just trying out Maya 2017 and seen that they've gone over to `PySide2`, which is great but all of my tools have `import PySide` or `from PySide import ...` in them.

The obvious solution would be to find/replace `import PySide` to `import PySide2` and hope everything still works after that, but I'd still like to be able to support older versions of Maya.

My idea was to have a single line solution to find/replace like:

```
import (PySide2 if "PySide2" in sys.modules else PySide)
```

But this returns: `Error: invalid syntax`

Does anyone have any ideas for an alternative to this? I'd like to try and keep it on a single line so it's an easy replacement for when I've got conditions like:

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could except the `ImportError` exception:

```
try:
    from Pyside2 import QtCore, QtGui

except ImportError:
    from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
```

Alternatively, you can use the `importlib` module:

```
import importlib
import sys

PySide = importlib.import_module('Pyside2' if 'Pyside2' in sys.modules else 'PySide')
```

Comment: Thank you! This is nice, if I put this at the top of all my scripts it should work nicely :)

Answer (score 0):

@user312016's answer worked nicely for "import" situations but less well for "from PySide import..." conditions. I ended up adding the following to my startup script which re-pathed everything nicely.

```
import sys
sys.modules['PySide'] = sys.modules['PySide2'] if 'PySide2' in sys.modules else sys.modules['PySide']
sys.modules['shiboken'] = sys.modules['shiboken2'] if 'shiboken2' in sys.modules else sys.modules['shiboken']
```

Comment: Oh and now I've realised that even this isn't perfect because the libraries have moved stuff around in PySide2 :D